# Is there any plugin to fail the build if number of characters in code file is more than 80

Tags: jenkins, plugins

Is there any plugin to fail the build if number of characters in code file is more than 80?

I want to make sure my code is in confirmation with code style before pushing the modified code remotely

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no jenkins plugin, this is can be done by a simple script.

Example in bash script:

```
lines_count=$(cat code_file | tr -d [:blank:] |  wc -m)
echo $lines_count
[ $lines_count -ge 80 ] && echo "Count greater than limit , failing the build" && exit 1
```

Run the above script from jenkins execute shell.

```
wc -m           : will count the characters in a file ( including spaces )
tr -d [:blank:] : will delete the space in the file
```

If you want spaces to be counted , remove tr command.